# Is it possible to run a Job every 20 seconds with Hangfire using dotNet?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, hangfire

Using Hangfire in dotNet core I can run a Job every 20 seconds using this expression:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => _anyService.GetMethodAsync(response.Data), "*/20 * * * * *");
```

But it's not working on asp.net, using:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<ISmoochService>("JOB", (data) => data.GetMethodAsync(param1, param2), "*/20 * * * * *");
```

I get this error:

'*/20 * * * * *' is an invalid crontab expression. It must contain 5 components of a schedule in the sequence of minutes, hours, days, months, and days of week.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for seconds in Hangfire cron expresions.

If you are just starting your project Hangfire alternative would be:
https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Answer (score 1):

Hangfire uses [Cron expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression) (via [Cron](https://api.hangfire.io/html/T_Hangfire_Cron.htm) class).

Cron is used for shceduling recurrent jobs and the smallest particle it supports is "a minute". A cron expression looks like `* * * * *` which is "minute hour day-of-month month day-of-week". So the shortest interval for Cron is 1 minute.

What you tried, dividing a particle of a cron expression (*/20), is generally supported by Cron (but not for seconds, which do not exist in Cron world). If you write */20 * * * * then it means every twenty minutes.

Conclusion: Hangfire is limited to Cron's limitations, which is minutes. If you really need scheduling on a shorter basis, try an alternative tool.

Answer (score -1):

You can change the default SchedulePollingInterval to 20 seconds

```
services.AddHangfireServer(option =>
{
    option.SchedulePollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
});
```